# SelectOneMenu always set 0 in backing bean property

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm doing a lazy table pagination with JSF (2.2) and JPA. The idea is select how many rows per page the datatable show through a `<h:selectOneMenu ... />` and AJAX, but when I select a value (5, 10, 15, 20, 25) the `itemsPerPage` property is always set to 0.

**View**

```
<h:outputLabel for="itemsPerPage" value="Items por página" />
<h:selectOneMenu id="itemsPerPage" styleClass="form-control"
    value="#{userPaginatorBean.itemsPerPage}"
    converter="javax.faces.Integer">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="5" itemLabel="5" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="10" itemLabel="10" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="15" itemLabel="15" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="20" itemLabel="20" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="25" itemLabel="25" />
    <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{userPaginatorBean.changeItemsPerPage}"
         execute="@this" render=":usersDatatable :messages" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

**Bean**

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class UserPaginatorBean implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private UserService userService;
    private List<User> users;
    ...
    private int itemsPerPage;
    private int totalPages;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        itemsPerPage = 5;
        totalPages = ((Long)userService.count()).intValue() / itemsPerPage;
        users = userService.getFirst(itemsPerPage);
    }

    // getters and setters

    public void changeItemsPerPage(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
        users = userService.getFirst(itemsPerPage);
        // always prints '0'
        System.out.println("New itemsPerPage value: " + itemsPerPage);
    }

    ...
}
```

No exception is thrown and `<h:messages id="messages" />` does not show anything.

¿Why is this happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a setter for `ItemsPerPage`?

Comment: Yes, `itemsPerPage` has a setter and getter.

Comment: Which server you are using?

Comment: I'm using WildFly 9.0.2.

Comment: I have faced this issue before and just when i changed to another server or (reinstall it) everything goes Okay.

Comment: Interesting. I'll install GlassFish to check.

Comment: I reproduced your code and just happened the expected. I used Wildfly 9.0.2. `System.out.println` in `changeItemsPerPage` printed exactly the value chosen in SelectOneMenu. Definitely the problem is not the web server.